# Iptables: How to allow only one ip through specific port?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, iptables

How can I on my ubuntu server, in Iptables only allow one IP adress on a specific port?

Thanks

Answer (score 63, accepted):

One liner:

```
iptables -I INPUT \! --src 1.2.3.4 -m tcp -p tcp --dport 777 -j DROP  # if it's not 1.2.3.4, drop it
```

A more elegant solution:

```
iptables -N xxx  # create a new chain named xxx
iptables -A xxx --src 1.2.3.4 -j ACCEPT  # allow 1.2.3.4
iptables -A xxx --src 1.2.3.5 -j ACCEPT  # allow 1.2.3.5
iptables -A xxx --src 1.2.3.6 -j ACCEPT  # allow 1.2.3.6
iptables -A xxx -j DROP  # drop everyone else
iptables -I INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 777 -j xxx  # use chain xxx for packets coming to TCP port 777
```

Comment: Do you know if I should also add this to the OUTPUT also?

Comment: @Camran: you need to be more specific. In this particular case, if you replace `INPUT` with `OUTPUT` you would block some packets sent using some addresses of the server itself (and not routed/forwarded). I doubt this makes sense, unless maybe you want to block programs that bind to some specific interfaces.

Comment: Don't forget you can also specify your sources in a chain like: `--src 1.2.3.4/30`

Comment: How would I later add a new allowed IP to the chain? Would I have to remove the DROP first, then enter the new user and insert the DROP again or is there a better solution?

Comment: @Matthias: `iptables -I xxx --src 7.8.9.10 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: `iptables -N xxx` does xxx mean chain name?

Comment: @AlexeySh. yes, but you can use other names as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from one of my CentOS systems (addresses have been obfuscated):

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp -s 1.2.3.4 -d 5.6.7.8 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: on centos, where to make this configuration permanent? (in ubuntu, we can use /etc/network/if-up.d/anyfile)

Comment: on CentOS it is: `service iptables save`.

Answer (score 0):

I use shorewall to configure IP table.  Use a rule like to accept from one host to port 123.

ACCEPT net:192.0.2.1 $FW tcp 1234